# Get image name onclick with Javascript before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I upload images from one file input, but before that I display them with javascript. I want to add a function to select the primary image on click. I want to store the clicked image's name in a hidden input. My problem is I can't get the image's original name by clicking on the image itself. I found a solution but that displays every images name.
For example I select these images:

```
Example.jpg, Example2.png, Example3.jpg
```

I display them like this:

```
<div class="uploaded-image" data-index="1" id="image-1">
  <img src="blob:http://localhost/5e75ca0e-f912-461e-98a6-9f8ad302bc84">
  <button class="delete-image"><i class="iui-close"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="uploaded-image" data-index="2" id="image-2">
  <img src="blob:http://localhost/5e75ca0e-f912-461e-98a6-9f831344adc84">
  <button class="delete-image"><i class="iui-close"></i></button>
</div>
```

And when I click on image-1, I'd like to get Example.jpg to a hidden text input, instead of blob:...

The only solution I found works with a button and displays all of them.
How can modify it to select the clicked image only?

This is the code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Show Details" onclick="FileDetails()">
```

```
function FileDetails() {

    // GET THE FILE INPUT.
    var fi = document.getElementById('image-upload');

    // VALIDATE OR CHECK IF ANY FILE IS SELECTED.
    if (fi.files.length > 0) {
            console.log(fi.files);

        // RUN A LOOP TO CHECK EACH SELECTED FILE.
        for (var i = 0; i <= fi.files.length - 1; i++) {
            fi.files[0] = document.getElementById('image-1')
            

            var fname = fi.files.item(i).name; // THE NAME OF THE FILE.
            console.log(fname);

        }
    } else {
        alert('Please select a file.')
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi how does that div gets generated show that code as well

Comment: It's generated by this image uploader: https://github.com/christianbayer/image-uploader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your plugin file there is already an event i.e : `$container.on("click", function(e) {` you can write your code there whenever `image` divs get clicked to add click image name inside input field .i.e:

```
 $container.on("click", function(e) {
   var fi = $("input[type=file]")[0];
   prevent(e);
   //**get files using index (0,1,2..) add value to input..**//
    $("#imgs").val(fi.files.item($(this).data('index')).name)
 });
```

***Demo Code*** :

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.imageUploader = function(options) {
    let defaults = {
      preloaded: [],
      imagesInputName: 'images',
      preloadedInputName: 'preloaded',
      label: 'Drag & Drop files here or click to browse',
      extensions: ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.svg'],
      mimes: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/svg+xml'],
      maxSize: undefined,
      maxFiles: undefined,
    };
    let plugin = this;
    let dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

    // The file input
    let $input;

    // Set empty settings
    plugin.settings = {};

    // Plugin constructor
    plugin.init = function() {

      // Define settings
      plugin.settings = $.extend(plugin.settings, defaults, options);

      // Run through the elements
      plugin.each(function(i, wrapper) {

        // Create the container
        let $container = createContainer();

        // Append the container to the wrapper
        $(wrapper).append($container);

        // Set some bindings
        $container.on("dragover", fileDragHover.bind($container));
        $container.on("dragleave", fileDragHover.bind($container));
        $container.on("drop", fileSelectHandler.bind($container));

        // If there are preloaded images
        if (plugin.settings.preloaded.length) {

          // Change style
          $container.addClass('has-files');

          // Get the upload images container
          let $uploadedContainer = $container.find('.uploaded');

          // Set preloaded images preview
          for (let i = 0; i < plugin.settings.preloaded.length; i++) {
            $uploadedContainer.append(createImg(plugin.settings.preloaded[i].src, plugin.settings.preloaded[i].id, true));
          }

        }

      });

    };

    let createContainer = function() {

      // Create the image uploader container
      let $container = $('<div>', {
        class: 'image-uploader'
      });

      // Create the input type file and append it to the container
      $input = $('<input>', {
        type: 'file',
        id: plugin.settings.imagesInputName + '-' + random(),
        name: plugin.settings.imagesInputName + '[]',
        accept: plugin.settings.extensions.join(','),
        multiple: ''
      }).appendTo($container);

      // Create the uploaded images container and append it to the container
      let $uploadedContainer = $('<div>', {
          class: 'uploaded'
        }).appendTo($container),

        // Create the text container and append it to the container
        $textContainer = $('<div>', {
          class: 'upload-text'
        }).appendTo($container),

        // Create the icon and append it to the text container
        $i = $('<i>', {
          class: 'iui-cloud-upload'
        }).appendTo($textContainer),

        // Create the text and append it to the text container
        $span = $('<span>', {
          text: plugin.settings.label
        }).appendTo($textContainer);


      // Listen to container click and trigger input file click
      $container.on('click', function(e) {
        // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
        prevent(e);

        // Trigger input click
        $input.trigger('click');
      });

      // Stop propagation on input click
      $input.on("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      });

      // Listen to input files changed
      $input.on('change', fileSelectHandler.bind($container));

      return $container;
    };


    let prevent = function(e) {
      // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    };

    let createImg = function(src, id, preloaded) {

      // Create the upladed image container
      let $container = $('<div>', {
          class: 'uploaded-image'
        }),

        // Create the img tag
        $img = $('<img>', {
          src: src
        }).appendTo($container),

        // Create the delete button
        $button = $('<button>', {
          class: 'delete-image'
        }).appendTo($container),

        // Create the delete icon
        $i = $('<i>', {
          class: 'iui-close'
        }).appendTo($button);


      // If the image is preloaded
      if (preloaded) {

        // Set a identifier
        $container.attr('data-preloaded', true);

        // Create the preloaded input and append it to the container
        let $preloaded = $('<input>', {
          type: 'hidden',
          name: plugin.settings.preloadedInputName + '[]',
          value: id
        }).appendTo($container)

      } else {

        // Set the index
        $container.attr('data-index', id);

      }

      //**** on click of image...***//
      $container.on("click", function(e) {
        var fi = $("input[type=file]")[0];
        prevent(e);
        console.log($(this).data('index'))
        console.log(fi.files.item($(this).data('index')).name);
        //**get files using index (0,1,2..) add value to input..**//
        $("#imgs").val(fi.files.item($(this).data('index')).name)
      });

      // Set delete action
      $button.on("click", function(e) {

        // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
        prevent(e);

        // Get the parent element
        let $parent = $container.parent();

        // If is not a preloaded image
        if ($container.data('preloaded') === true) {

          // Remove from preloaded array
          plugin.settings.preloaded = plugin.settings.preloaded.filter(function(p) {
            return p.id !== id;
          });

        } else {

          // Get the image index
          let index = parseInt($container.data('index'));

          // Update other indexes
          $parent.find('.uploaded-image[data-index]').each(function(i, cont) {
            if (i > index) {
              $(cont).attr('data-index', i - 1);
            }
          });

          // Remove the file from input
          dataTransfer.items.remove(index);

          // Update input files
          $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);
        }

        // Remove this image from the container
        $container.remove();

        // If there is no more uploaded files
        if (!$parent.children().length) {

          // Remove the 'has-files' class
          $parent.parent().removeClass('has-files');

        }

      });

      return $container;
    };

    let fileDragHover = function(e) {

      // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
      prevent(e);

      // Change the container style
      if (e.type === "dragover") {
        $(this).addClass('drag-over');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('drag-over');
      }
    };

    let fileSelectHandler = function(e) {

      // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
      prevent(e);

      // Get the jQuery element instance
      let $container = $(this);

      // Get the files as an array of files
      let files = Array.from(e.target.files || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);

      // Will keep only the valid files
      let validFiles = [];

      // Run through the files
      $(files).each(function(i, file) {
        // Run the validations
        if (plugin.settings.extensions && !validateExtension(file)) {
          return;
        }
        if (plugin.settings.mimes && !validateMIME(file)) {
          return;
        }
        if (plugin.settings.maxSize && !validateMaxSize(file)) {
          return;
        }
        if (plugin.settings.maxFiles && !validateMaxFiles(validFiles.length, file)) {
          return;
        }
        validFiles.push(file);
      });

      // If there is at least one valid file
      if (validFiles.length) {
        // Change the container style
        $container.removeClass('drag-over');

        // Makes the upload
        setPreview($container, validFiles);
      } else {

        // Update input files (it is now empty due to a default browser action)
        $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);

      }
    };

    let validateExtension = function(file) {

      if (plugin.settings.extensions.indexOf(file.name.replace(new RegExp('^.*\\.'), '.')) < 0) {
        alert(`The file "${file.name}" does not match with the accepted file extensions: "${plugin.settings.extensions.join('", "')}"`);

        return false;
      }

      return true;
    };

    let validateMIME = function(file) {

      if (plugin.settings.mimes.indexOf(file.type) < 0) {
        alert(`The file "${file.name}" does not match with the accepted mime types: "${plugin.settings.mimes.join('", "')}"`);

        return false;
      }

      return true;
    };

    let validateMaxSize = function(file) {

      if (file.size > plugin.settings.maxSize) {
        alert(`The file "${file.name}" exceeds the maximum size of ${plugin.settings.maxSize / 1024 / 1024}Mb`);

        return false;
      }

      return true;

    };

    let validateMaxFiles = function(index, file) {

      if ((index + dataTransfer.items.length + plugin.settings.preloaded.length) >= plugin.settings.maxFiles) {
        alert(`The file "${file.name}" could not be added because the limit of ${plugin.settings.maxFiles} files was reached`);

        return false;
      }

      return true;

    };

    let setPreview = function($container, files) {

      // Add the 'has-files' class
      $container.addClass('has-files');

      // Get the upload images container
      let $uploadedContainer = $container.find('.uploaded'),

        // Get the files input
        $input = $container.find('input[type="file"]');

      // Run through the files
      $(files).each(function(i, file) {

        // Add it to data transfer
        dataTransfer.items.add(file);

        // Set preview
        $uploadedContainer.append(createImg(URL.createObjectURL(file), dataTransfer.items.length - 1), false);

      });

      // Update input files
      $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);

    };

    // Generate a random id
    let random = function() {
      return Date.now() + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    };

    this.init();

    // Return the instance
    return this;
  };

}(jQuery));
$('.input-images').imageUploader();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="imgs">
<div class="input-images"></div>
```

Comment: I would have one last question if you're still here. I'd like to change the class of the clicked image only. Could you show me how to do that inside this click function?

Comment: Yes , you can use `$(this).addClass("something")` .Also, don't forget to remove class from other divs i.e : `$(".uploaded-image").removeClass("something")`

Comment: And how can I change it back if the user clicks on another image?

Comment: HI, you can simply remove class from other divs i.e : `$(".uploaded-image").removeClass("something")`